# How to change the font in my app based on Locale?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView hi;
    Typeface ty;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hi);
        ty = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets() , "fonts/Spirax-Regular.ttf");

        hi.setTypeface(ty);
    }
}
```

this code worked very well for me.
My question is if my application support two languages which are (Arabic and English), is there any way to add two types of fonts to the same text? one for the Arabic Text and the other for the English one?

Comment: On the basis of current  Locale `getResources().getConfiguration().locale;` you can differentiate text and set two different Typeface!

Comment: Where to out this? 
and where to to put the thy type name in this code?

Comment: I have posted the answered, please check that !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language().equals("ar")){
        //LANGUAGE IS ARABIC
        text.setTypeface(arabicTypeface);
    }
    else{
        //LANGUAGE IS ENGLISH
        text.setTypeface(englishTypeface);
    }
```

Comment: I make it like this, but it did not work. the font inside **else** is the one which work: for example if i put the arabic font inside **else**  it is work but english is not, vice versa

Comment: thats it `if(Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language().equals("ar")){
            //LANGUAGE IS ARABIC
            hi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hi);
            tyAr = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets() , "fonts/Amiri-Slanted.ttf");
            hi.setTypeface(tyAr);
        }else{
            //LANGUAGE IS ENGLISH
            hi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hi);
            tyEn = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets() , "fonts/Spirax-Regular.ttf");
            hi.setTypeface(tyEn)}}`

Comment: There must be something wrong with the typefaces, are you sure they are different?

Comment: And did you change your device language?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way but this will solve your problem

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

This type of example is use to simply change the text font.

Comment: What to put instead of **Html** ?the font name?

Comment: No required any font name just you can simply used whenever you used simply textview means in your code set like hi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hi); and after set hi.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

Comment: Here you can replace text to any type of string like eng, arabic, hindi any.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    hi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage().equals("ar"))
        hi.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets() , "YOUR ARABIC .TTF FILE HERE"));
    else if(getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage().equals("en"))
        hi.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets() , "YOUR ENGLISH .TTF FILE HERE"));
}
```

Comment: i am really sorry, i don not know why it is not work too! i just change the _Your English_ to the font i want nothing else. why it did not work then

Comment: Do you have those .ttf files in your assets folder?

Comment: Yes, if not it would throw a NPE

Comment: yes i have two .ttf files, one for arabic the other for english. in the code you give me, the displayed font is the one inside **else** when i change "ar" to "en" in **if** statement.
can any one make it from zero for me with the fonts i mentioned? -if you can of course-